# PHP conditionals showing both results

Tags: php, html

I have the following on a php page which does not want to work correctly. I am not sure if i'm not doing the conditional correctly or not? It appears to show both sets of content irrespective if the 1st condition is true or not, any ideas?

```
 <? if(!isset($_SESSION['exhibitor_logged_in']) || $_SESSION['exhibitor_logged_in'] != true): ?>
    <p>Please log in with the password.</p>
    <form name="exhibitor_login" method="POST" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="submit">&nbsp;</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOG IN" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <? else: ?>
        <p>Logged in</p>
    <? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change all of you `<?` to `<?php` php isn't being parsed. You can confirm by viewing source on the web page.

Comment: That depends on the server config. However, it's indeed the most likely reason.

Comment: Hi Orangepill, thank you, am I right to assume this is a setting on the server?

Comment: A conditional will evaluate on why or the other regardless of how broken the conditional is. The only way he could be hitting both conditions is if the expression wasn't being evaluated at all

Comment: Correct its called short open tags

Answer (score 2):

Change all `<?` to `<?php`,

or modify your **php.ini** file, change `short_open_tag = Off` to `short_open_tag = On`

but short open tags are not recommended, you can see [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score -1):

Using `||` will make and or comparation between the two statment, i think in your case you should use `&&` because it should match both statment

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['exhibitor_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['exhibitor_logged_in'] != true):
```

Comment: Unlikely. Accessing something after determining that it is not set makes no sense at all.